# Illegal Property error in parsing SOAP response

Tags: android, web-services, soap, ksoap2

I'm working on an android app that utilizes my web services to fetch data and display it. My SOAP response is a bit complex and it looks like this.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
<soap:Body>
<GetSessionDetailsResponse xmlns="https://viberservices.com/gcdev/">
  <GetSessionDetailsResult>
    <ModuleFlags>string</ModuleFlags>
    <SessionID>string</SessionID>
    <UserInfo>
      <Fullname>string</Fullname>
      <Language>long</Language>
    </UserInfo>
    <Locations>
      <LocationDetails>
        <LocationID>long</LocationID>
        <LocationName>string</LocationName>
        <PhotoURL>string</PhotoURL>
      </LocationDetails>
      <LocationDetails>
        <LocationID>long</LocationID>
        <LocationName>string</LocationName>
        <PhotoURL>string</PhotoURL>
      </LocationDetails>
    </Locations>
  </GetSessionDetailsResult>
</GetSessionDetailsResponse>
```

Now I want to get the Location ID and Location Name data from the Location part. And I'm using the following code.

```
SoapObject res=(SoapObject)envelope.bodyIn;
SoapObject t=(SoapObject)res.getProperty("Locations");
for(int i=0; i<t.getPropertyCount(); i++){
    SoapObject locinfo=(SoapObject)t.getProperty(i);
    String lid= locinfo.getProperty("LocationID").toString();
    String lname= locinfo.getProperty("LocationName").toString();
}
//Code to display lid and lname
```

But I get a run time exception saying **java.lang.RuntimeException: illegal property: Locations**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to overcome this by using the following code:

```
SoapObject res=(SoapObject)envelope.bodyIn;
SoapObject root=(SoapObject)((SoapObject)res.getProperty("GetSessionDetailsResult")).getProperty("Locations");
for(int i=0; i<root.getPropertyCount(); i++){
    SoapObject t=(SoapObject)root.getProperty(i);
    String lid= t.getProperty("LocationID").toString();
    String lname= t.getProperty("LocationName").toString();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Android Sax Parser :

SAXXMLParser:

```
public class SAXXMLParser {

public static List<Location> parse(String input) {
    List<Location> locations = null;

    try {
        // create a XMLReader from SAXParser
        XMLReader xmlReader = SAXParserFactory.newInstance().newSAXParser()
                .getXMLReader();
        // create a SAXXMLHandler
        SAXXMLHandler saxHandler = new SAXXMLHandler();
        // store handler in XMLReader
        xmlReader.setContentHandler(saxHandler);
        // the process starts
        xmlReader.parse(input);
        // get the `Locations list`
        locations = saxHandler.getEmployees();

    } catch (Exception ex) {
        Log.d("XML", "SAXXMLParser: parse() failed");
    }

    // return location list
    return locations;
}

}
```

SAXXMLHandler :

```
import org.xml.sax.Attributes;
import org.xml.sax.SAXException;
import org.xml.sax.helpers.DefaultHandler;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;


public class SAXXMLHandler extends DefaultHandler {


private List<Location> locations;
private String tempVal;
// to maintain context
private Location location;

public SAXXMLHandlerTest() {
    locations = new ArrayList<Location>();
}

public List<Location> getEmployees() {
    return locations;
}

// Event Handlers
public void startElement(String uri, String localName, String qName,
                         Attributes attributes) throws SAXException {
    // reset
    tempVal = "";
    if (qName.equalsIgnoreCase("LocationDetails")) {
        // create a new instance of location
        location = new Location();
    }
}

public void characters(char[] ch, int start, int length)
        throws SAXException {
    tempVal = new String(ch, start, length);
}

public void endElement(String uri, String localName, String qName)
        throws SAXException {
    if (qName.equalsIgnoreCase("LocationDetails")) {
        // add it to the list
        locations.add(location);
    } else if (qName.equalsIgnoreCase("LocationID")) {
        location.setLocationID(Long.parseLong(tempVal));
    } else if (qName.equalsIgnoreCase("LocationName")) {
        location.setLocationName(tempVal);
    } else if (qName.equalsIgnoreCase("PhotoURL")) {
        location.setPhotoURL(tempVal);
    }
}

}
```

Model class :

```
public class Location {


private long LocationID;
private String LocationName;
private String PhotoURL;

public long getLocationID() {
    return LocationID;
}

public void setLocationID(long locationID) {
    LocationID = locationID;
}

public String getLocationName() {
    return LocationName;
}

public void setLocationName(String locationName) {
    LocationName = locationName;
}

public String getPhotoURL() {
    return PhotoURL;
}

public void setPhotoURL(String photoURL) {
    PhotoURL = photoURL;
}

}
```

Use this code in your activity/fragment to parse data

```
  List<Location> locations = SAXXMLParsertest.parse("Your xml data");

    if (locations != null && locations.size() > 0) {

        for (int i = 0; i < locations.size(); i++) {

            Log.e("Location name", " " + locations.get(i).getLocationName());
            Log.e("Location Id", " " + locations.get(i).getLocationID());
            Log.e("Photo Uri", " " + locations.get(i).getPhotoURL());

        }
    }
```